# ASP.NET Web API Security Token Generation Mechanism

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I am using ASP.NET Web API to generate publicly accessible services that can be used by authenticated users.  I am using token based authentication (OAuth Bearer tokens).  ASP.NET has everything inbuilt.  I have the following clarifications

- What is the exact process used to generate this token internally.  Is the framework using some sort of key?
- How will this work if I move this to a farm environment.

Answer (score 1):

For first point yes, it is using the machine.config file and reads they key for encryption from there.
For the second point, you can unify this key value in the machine.config for all the nodes on the farm, or you can override it in your web.config. My recommendation is to unify it on all nodes.